# Sensor identification

Tags: temperature, sensors

When I run `sensors` I get:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +52.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I have a quad-core i5 processor.

How do I identify what Physical id 0 and temp1 stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Physical id 0 is your CPU

Core0 is your first individual core

Core1 is your second individual core

Comment: What about core 3 and 4? I have a quad-core i5 processor.

Comment: @ToDo I believe two of those cores are virtual cores, although, I could be mistaken. Only physical cores have temperatures. To be sure, go ahead and run `sudo sensors-detect` follow the instructions closely just don't agree yes to the one that's "risky".

Comment: And what about `temp1`?

Answer (score 1):

From ([tomshardware.com - Is Intel i5 Dual Core or Quad Core?](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/277574-28-intel-dual-core-quad-core)) you get this answer:

> i5-750 is a quad core, all other i5s are dual cores, albeit with
>   hyperthreading.

That answer is from 2010 but you get the point. All i7's are definitely quad core.

The next answer on the same link goes on to say:

> what he said, Intel is confusing uneducated customers this time
>   around. I do not mean uneducated = stupid either, i mean that the
>   average user that walks into best buy who does not know what to look
>   for in a CPU...

Based on reporting from `sensors` you almost certainly have a dual core processor.

My i7 processor from 2012/2013 is reported correctly:

```
$ sensors
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3906 RPM
CPU:            +80.0°C  
Ambient:        +48.0°C  
GPU:            +67.0°C  
Other:          +77.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +82.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +82.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +80.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:         +77.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:         +73.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I have a huge problem with temperatures and fan speed, but the number of cores are correct.

If you doubt `sensors` you can double check using:

```
ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/
cpu0  cpu3  cpu6     cpuidle       isolated    modalias  possible  uevent
cpu1  cpu4  cpu7     hotplug       kernel_max  offline   power
cpu2  cpu5  cpufreq  intel_pstate  microcode   online    present
```

With a dual core (hyper-threading) you'll see CPU0 to CPU3. In this example it's a quad core so CPU0 to CPU7 appear.

To answer your second question of `Temp 1` note that sensors is missing one of the temps in my situation which you can confirm on your platform by using:

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
27800
29800
78000
```

Comment: hmmm, the Intel spec page for my i5-4440S clearly states it has 4 cores.  It also states it is not hyperthreaded.  Are they lying? Sad, if so.  Or are the commentors at Tom's wrong. http://ark.intel.com/products/75040/Intel-Core-i5-4440S-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz

Comment: CPU world also states the i5-4440S has 4 physical cores.  http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i5/Intel-Core%20i5-4440S.html

Comment: The  i5-4440S was launched Q3'13. The Tom's articles were for processors as of 2010. Are you having same issue with sensors as OP?